# Why are the two shades of the same color in this figure?

Tags: plotting, color

Given $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ I am trying to plot $f(S)$ for given complex valued function $f$

Looking at other answers on this site for similar questions, I came up with 
this

```
f = Function[z, 1/Conjugate[z]];

(*Plot limit parameters*)
plimit = 1;
space = 2;
plrange = {{Re[f[-plimit]] - space, Re[f[plimit]] + space},
           {Im[f[-plimit]] - space, Im[f[plimit]] + space}}

ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@({Re[f[z]], Im[f[z]]}*Boole[Abs[z] < 1] /. z -> x + I*y),
  {x, -plimit, plimit},
  {y, -plimit, plimit}, (*Indicates the rectablge from which the points satisfying Boole[..]==1 will be picked.*)
  PlotRange -> plrange
]
```

The result of this command is

[image]

My question is why are there two different colors in this image? One light 
and one dark. Is the plot trying to tell me something here?

**SYSTEM INFORMATION:**
Version 8.0.1.0
Platform Linux x86(32-bit)
Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: I don't see this behavior on MacOSX and *Mathematica* 8.0.4. Can you please include information about your system into the question?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: I can't see it because it keeps crashing the kernel in V9; I see the shading all the way across in V8.0.4 (not stopping at $y = - x$).  There is a discontinuity at `Abs[z] == 1`, where the parametrization collapses to `{0, 0}` -- perhaps you want to consider `RegionFunction`, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do..

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have  the same, and it seems to be related to the `Boole` expression.

Comment: This works for me: `With[{z = x + I*y},
 ParametricPlot[{Re[f[z]]*Boole[Abs[z] < 1], 
   Im[f[z]]*Boole[Abs[z] < 1]}, {x, -plimit, plimit}, {y, -plimit, 
   plimit}, PlotRange -> plrange, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 > 1]]]`

Comment: @ Sjoerd C.de Vries Your code seems to give me the same result as mine on my system. I think it must be a Mathematica bug. However when I increase the radius of the disc to 2, I dont have this problem

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Nope, doesn't work here. Especially when I change the size of the graphics, then the dark and bright regions jump around and change their shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what we see here is some over-folding artifact. You can prevent this by using `RegionFunction` to restrict the *outside* region used to a reasonable size

```
f = Function[z, 1/Conjugate[z]];
plimit = 1;
space = 2;
plrange = {{Re[f[-plimit]] - space, 
    Re[f[plimit]] + space}, {Im[f[-plimit]] - space, 
    Im[f[plimit]] + space}};

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@({Re[f[z]], Im[f[z]]}*Boole[Abs[z] < 1] /. 
    z -> x + I*y), {x, -plimit, plimit}, {y, -plimit, plimit},
 PlotRange -> plrange,
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, -5 < x < 5 && -5 < y < 5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Still, since your example crashes version 9 on my Linux box, I believe there is some deeper issue here indicating a bug in *Mathematica*. Maybe it doesn't like when you turn the complex plane inside out...

[image]

```
pts = Table[{i, j}, {j, -3, 3, .5}, {i, -3, 3, .5}];
m[{x_, y_}] := {x, y}/(x^2 + y^2 + $MachineEpsilon)
Manipulate[
 With[{points = (1 - r)*pts + r*Map[m, pts, {2}]},
  Graphics[{Line /@ points, Line /@ Transpose[points]}]
  ],
 {r, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: This seems like a good work around. Thanks.